# Part2: How to fix leak at bottom of double hung vinyl window

Tags: windows, leaking

In Part 1 I posted a photo of the pocket sill that my lower sash closes into. Search "How to fix leak at bottom of double-hung vinyl window. In Part2 (this posting) How to fix leak at bottom of the double-hung vinyl window, you're seeing an exterior photo of a portion of the bottom sash, black bubble weatherstripping seal, white pocket sill with a 1-inch white interior lip, and 1/2 inch black exterior lip .

Okay, Kyle was very helpful with Part 1. First I removed the weep hole covers and scraped off debris partly blocking the weep holes. By aiming a hose into the openings of each side of the pocket sill the debris under the sill was washed away via the weep holes. I replaced the weep hole-hinged covers and tested the window for leaks, by aiming a gentle hose spray on the lower sash for 12 minutes in the first window, and no leaks. Same for the second window. So, Kyle, you saved two windows. Thanks!

In the third and 4th windows (this posting), in less than a minute the water oozed up and over one of the front corners of the white 1-inch lip into the house.  The pocket sill had almost no water in it. So for the 3rd and 4th windows, the weep holes were not the issue. Maybe the bubble seals on the bottom of the sash need replacement? (this photo indicates that the end bubble seal and the white bubble seal behind it (not seen) were loose. Since the ends of the two bubble seals were lose, this could possibly be the cause of the leak over the white lip into the house There is a double-pile of weatherstripping on each side of the sash, but do not think that is where the leak is from. Perhaps it is from the seal between the pane and the sash? My guess is water is flowing below the two bubble seals at these loose ends and splashing over the white lip into the house. Maybe changing both bubble weatherstripping seals might cure the problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image: bottom sash, seal, pocket sill from exterior]

[image: exterior of sash, bubble seal loose at end, 1 inch lip of pocket sill and 1/2 inch black lip of sill]

Comment: You may have had a hard time posting a photo, but think of how hard a time we'll have trying to figure out what the issue is "by braille". No pics of the new windows makes it hard for people to identify what's going on. If you want help, put in some effort to help us help you. Also, a link to your other question would be nice instead of making people go search for it. Again, help us help you.

Comment: I did post  2 new photos, but only one was accepted. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I fixed up the image link for you. It can take a sec to get your head wrapped around it.

Comment: Thank you, Freeman. Two of my 4 leaky windows have stopped leaking due me following to Kyle's weep hole advice. I was hoping I would have the same luck with advice about the cause of the the two remaining leaky windows. that do not appear to have weep hole involvement, but maybe there is no easy fix.

Comment: Were the weep holes in the other 2 windows "factory" or did they look "home made"? Maybe you will need to add them to these windows.

Comment: So I fixed the leaks in the other two windows with the same weep hole cleaning and added two new bubble seals. So you guys helped me a lot.  However, there is one remaining leaking window.  I changed the bubble seals and the weep holes work find. However, within 15 seconds of spraying the lower sash, water heavily leaks over both corners of the front corner of the 1-inch lip of the pocket sill into the house.